# How to insert new GET Request fields in an AngularJS App, and show/hide multiple screens based on that?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, redux, get, rxjs

I have multiple Screen that uses custom Endpoints from our API. In the GET/environment we have a new field `isItAvailable`.

I want to hide multiple elements on Multiple Screens. I am using AngularJS 1.5.x. The GET/Routes have been set already.

I also have another problem. 2 of the screens have only Views and Controllers. The other one has been ported with Redux. How would you handle that change?

Here is my Code.

Please, I am very new to this, so be descriptive.

Comment: Can you show us your code

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. I know it is not much, but I can't share the code. What I can do is try to post some stuff, after I redact them. Would that help?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/20675257).